What's the point of declaring the main function's formal arguments as "int argc, char* argv[argc+1]"?
I typically declare the main function's formal arguments as either int argc, char* argv[] or int argc, char** argv to take in the actual arguments from the command line. But I noticed a senior C programmer, who also happened to be a member of the ISO committee and co-author of the C23 revision, uses int argc, char* argv[argc+1], or int argc, char* argv[argc]. What is the point of doing that?

You're sure they use both argv[argc+1] and argv[argc]?  That seems very odd.

Does it compile if you use -Werror?

@underloaded_operator it should compile with a compliant C11 compiler.

@underloaded_operator If only -Werror used, yes! But not when clubbed with -Weverything.

@datenwolf A compliant C11 (and C17) compiler could also be rejecting it if I'm not mistaken. I think this folllows with VLAs that became optionally supported in C11 (and mandatory again in C23).

hello, Bob. i'm curious, did you ask the programmer this question?

@user14063792468 I'm pretty sure this refers to the author of Modern C, in which case you don't really need to ask him (although he is an active user on SO) but just look it up in the book.

@Lundin nor me, nor OP have this book. that's why he is really asking.

@user14063792468 It's available for free as pdf. It only costs money if you want a physical book. Follow the link in my answer. And I'm pretty sure the OP's question is about the style used in the book.

@TedLyngmo No, most compliant C11 and C17 compilers will accept this code. I am not aware of a single compiler on the market implementing both __STDC__ and __STDC_NO_VLA__.

@Lundin i do not get you both. the OP, and you. if OP knows the answer, and you know the answer. that is how i understood your comment. so author explains the point. so anyone could look it up in the book. you and OP seem to know the point well. i am confused. what this question for? what's your answer for?

@Lundin Do you agree that the C11 and C17 standards allows for a compliant compiler to reject it? I assume you do and that's all I meant, without actually knowing of any otherwise compliant compiler that actually rejects it.

@user14063792468 Not all questions are well-researched. There's just so many ISO C 9899:202x WG members who match the description, I can only think of one, who also happens to be the author of a book where this style is present. Then I applied common sense from there on.

@TedLyngmo Yeah it would be valid for a older, C11/C17 conforming compiler to reject it but only if it defines the mentioned constants. Which isn't the case with for example the non-C compiler called MSVC, which can't claim any form of (C95 or later) compliance without first declaring __STDC__.

@Lundin Afaik, the change in C23 isn't retroactive, so if someone created a new C11/17 compiler it still wouldn't need to support it. Sidenote: MSVC also has /Zc:__STDC__ available in C11 and C17 mode. They didn't set it by default since it's a breaking change. I'm not sure about how conforming it becomes with that set. Probably not very... :-)

@TedLyngmo As ISO standards work, there is only one version of the C language and that is ISO 9899:2024. Previous standards are withdrawn. Programming doesn't quite work like that of course, but in other areas of engineering, simply following the latest standard is normal practice. As for MSVC's various /Z switches, if I remember correctly they'll force the compiler into strict C89 mode. /Zc:__STDC__ is some recent update as per version 17 from 2022, where they finally just might have brought the compiler into year 1989 + amendments conformance. Bleeding edge compiler, that one...

@Lundin :-) ... but it is at least slow so that all the little bits don't get stressed out.

@TedLyngmo Maybe they compiled VS2022 using MSVC and the compilation started in year 1995. That would explain a lot of things!

The following parameter declarations are equivalent:

int argc, char* argv[argc]
int argc, char* argv[argc+1]
int argc, char* argv[]
int argc, char** argv

This equivalence is spelled out in section 6.7.6.3p7 of the C standard:

A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to
‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are
those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation.
If the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array
type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the
corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first
element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the
size expression

By the above paragraph, the first three cases are adjusted to be equivalent to the fourth.  And as there's no static qualifier in any of those cases, it doesn't fall under any exceptions.
The developer likely did this as a form of internal documentation to illustrate the sizes of these arrays.

So it was already correct in C99?

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes, the same language is in C99 6.7.5.3p7.

Not quite equivalent, char *argv[argc] before adjustment declares a variable-length array while char *argv[] does not. So a C 2011-2018 compiler that did not support variable-length arrays could reject the former but not the latter.


What is the point of doing that?

For people and static code analyzers, the char* argv[argc+1] correctly points out that arg[] may be accessed (e.g. read the pointer) for indexes [0...argc].
Note: argv[argc] is expected to be NULL.
C99, C23 and optionally C11, C17, see the 4 as equivalent.

Subclause 6.7.6.2, paragraph 1, of C11 ISO/IEC 9899:2011 says

The [ and ] may delimit an expression or *. If they delimit an
expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression
shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant
expression, it shall  have a value greater than zero.

Such an array declaration as a function argument provides a compiler with information about the relationship between arguments, specifically, which argument specifies the valid length within which a passed array may be indexed.
This can be used for either static analysis, or for automatic generation of argument validation code in debug builds or where robustness and defensive execution are important.

I belive this is referring to Jens Gustedt and his book Modern C, which teaches this style.
The book does give a rationale early on in the the "buckle up" chapter: "We use array notation for pointer parameters.: We do so whenever these assume that the pointer can't be null." And then he gives the example of argv[argc+1] (as well as another example char const string[static 1]).
The argc+1 part is given this extra rationale:

The second summarizes the fact that main receives an array of pointers to char: the program name, argc-1 program arguments, and one null pointer that terminates the array.

So that is the reason why he is using that style. Not everyone might even be aware that accessing argv[argc] is guaranteed to give a null pointer.
A similar style is often used for strings as well, for example malloc( sizeof(char[n+1]) ) where the +1 is self-documenting code showing that care was taken to allocate space for the nul terminator. Self-documenting code is good code, in general.
Apart from making code more readable and self-documenting, typing things out explicitly like this improves the possibilities for compilers and static analyzers to give better diagnostics, for example by pointing out array out of bounds bugs.
